# Unable to upsert customer data via Data Loader [Failed to parse date: 29/02/YYYY]

Tags: data-loader

new to SF here.

I have done a data upsert to update customer profile. This profile upsert have been done for many times (weekly basis) without problem.

But this time the problem occur with customer profile who have the birthdate of "29 February"

Example of error message:

> Error converting value to correct data type: Failed to parse date:
> 29/02/1972

Other profile other than "29 February" have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/), [XL-Connector 365](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler4excel-365/), or [G-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-g-connector/) instead and work directly from your preferred worksheet.
Not only you won't need to waste time on preparing CSV files and analyzing result files, but it will also automatically recognize dates and other types and convert them to what salesforce expects.